# Filter list based on JSON string child

Tags: json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, filter, reduce

I have an object with recipes in my React app, which I'm trying to filter based on clicked ingredient filters. Every recipe has a JSON string, filled with recipes (see my recipe object below).

Currently I'm stuck after I've succesfully filtered my recipe list, but ending up with a list of empty objects and correctly filtered recipe objects.

I somehow need to remove or reduce (see my futile attempt below) these empty objects.

```
const filteredArray = this.state.recipes.map(recipe => {
    const ingredients = JSON.parse(recipe.ingredients);
    const filtered = ingredients.filter(ingredient => selectedFilters.includes(ingredient.id))
    .reduce(() => {
        return recipe;
    }, {});
});
```

Below an example of my `this.state.recipes` object:

```
{
    id: 42
    image: "/path/to/image.png"
    ingredients: "[{"id": 192, "name": "Cachaça"},{"id": 243, "name": "Sugar"},{"id": 27, "name": "Lime"},{"id": 28, "name": "Icecubes"}]"
    name: "Caipirinha"
    short: "short description"
},
{
    id: 43
    image: "/path/to/image.png"
    ingredients: "[{"id": 192, "name": "Cachaça"},{"id": 33, "name": "Espresso"},{"id": 243, "name": "Sugar"},{"id": 27, "name": "Lime"},{"id": 28, "name": "Icecubes"}]"
    name: "Caipirinha coffee"
    short: "short description"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.state.recipes.filter(recipe => {
  const ingredients = JSON.parse(recipe.ingredients);

  return ingredients.findIndex(ingredient => selectedFilters.includes(ingredient.id)) !== -1;
});
```